# Dual monitor doesn't work (Ubuntu 18.04 + KDE Plasma 5.12.4)

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde, amd-graphics

I had 'standard' Ubuntu + Gnome, but after another update x-server and Gnome died.
Yesterday my colleague installed KDE Plasma for me. But now second display doesn't work.
In 'System Settings' it shows 2 displays (DisplayPort 0 and 1), but I can't enable second monitor. If I check 'Enable', and press 'Apply' the Enable check dissapears.
GPU: AMD Radeon Pro WX3100 (Polaris 12)
[image]

Interestingly, if I swap two cables, the Login dialog shows up on the second monitor, but then the system still works on the first one. How does it know which monitor is which?